# Pandas: Groupby and codition

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, group-by, conditional-statements

I have the below mod_df data frame with various symbols and its corresponding prices. ['Lower Low']: is a column which is used to find the Lower Low price values. The below mentioned piece of code is the condition applied for mod_df['Lower Low'] column and it works fine.

```
data = {'Symbol': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
        'Date': ['2023-05-15 15:00:00', '2023-05-15 22:00:00', '2023-05-16 07:00:00', '2023-05-16 14:00:00',
                 '2023-05-17 07:00:00', '2023-05-17 20:00:00', '2023-05-18 02:00:00', '2023-05-18 16:00:00',
                 '2023-05-19 07:00:00', '2023-05-22 09:00:00', '2023-05-15 00:00:00',
                 '2023-05-16 12:00:00', '2023-05-17 06:00:00', '2023-05-18 02:00:00'],
        'Price': [0.90065, 0.90042, 0.89841, 0.89462, 0.89437, 0.89455, 0.89248, 0.89013, 0.89405, 0.89424, 0.59601,
                  0.59548, 0.59444, 0.59527],
        'Helper_L': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1],

        }

mod_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
mod_df['Lower Low'] = np.where((mod_df['Helper_L'] != mod_df['Helper_L'].shift(-1))
                               & (mod_df['Price'] < mod_df['Price'].shift(1))
                               & (mod_df['Price'] < mod_df['Price'].shift(-1)), 'Lower Low', '')

print(mod_df)

Symbol       Date         Price  Helper_L Lower Low
A   15-05-2023 15:00:00  0.90065    0   
A   15-05-2023 22:00:00  0.90042    0   
A   16-05-2023 07:00:00  0.89841    0   
A   16-05-2023 14:00:00  0.89462    0   
A   17-05-2023 07:00:00  0.89437    0   Lower Low
A   17-05-2023 20:00:00  0.89455    1   
A   18-05-2023 02:00:00  0.89248    1   
A   18-05-2023 16:00:00  0.89013    1   Lower Low
A   19-05-2023 07:00:00  0.89405    2   
A   22-05-2023 09:00:00  0.89424    3   
B   15-05-2023 00:00:00  0.59601    0   
B   16-05-2023 12:00:00  0.59548    0   
B   17-05-2023 06:00:00  0.59444    0   Lower Low
B   18-05-2023 02:00:00  0.59527    1
```

Since I have different Symbols in Symbol column, I'm trying to use below code for mod_df['Lower Low'] column using groupby and Lambda function to group by symbol but I get the error:
I get the error: KeyError: 'Helper_L'
Could anyone suggest how to fix this?

```
mod_df['Lower Low'] = mod_df.groupby('Symbol')[['Helper_L','Price']]\
    .transform(lambda df: np.where((df['Helper_L'] !=df['Helper_L'].shift(-1)) & (df['Price'] < df['Price'].shift(1))
                                   & (df['Price'] < df['Price'].shift(-1)), 'Lower Low', ''))
```

Comment: try `apply` instead of `transform`. I believe `transform` is used per column at a time

Comment: apply() implicitly passes all the columns (or rows - see axis param) for each group as a DataFrame to the custom function. transform() passes each column for each group individually as a Series to the custom function. The custom function passed to apply can return a scalar, or a Series or DataFrame (or numpy array or even list). The custom function passed to transform must return a sequence (a one dimensional Series, array or list) the same length as the group.

Answer (score 0):

No need to apply labmda function.. you can do a `groupby` + `shift` on the required columns then use `np.where` to select values in an efficient manner

```
g = mod_df.groupby('Symbol')

mod_df['Lower Low'] = np.where(
    (mod_df['Helper_L'] != g['Helper_L'].shift(-1))
    & (mod_df['Price'] < g['Price'].shift( 1))
    & (mod_df['Price'] < g['Price'].shift(-1)), 
    'Lower Low', ''
)
```

Result

```
   Symbol                 Date    Price  Helper_L  Lower Low
0       A  2023-05-15 15:00:00  0.90065         0           
1       A  2023-05-15 22:00:00  0.90042         0           
2       A  2023-05-16 07:00:00  0.89841         0           
3       A  2023-05-16 14:00:00  0.89462         0           
4       A  2023-05-17 07:00:00  0.89437         0  Lower Low
5       A  2023-05-17 20:00:00  0.89455         1           
6       A  2023-05-18 02:00:00  0.89248         1           
7       A  2023-05-18 16:00:00  0.89013         1  Lower Low
8       A  2023-05-19 07:00:00  0.89405         2           
9       A  2023-05-22 09:00:00  0.89424         3           
10      B  2023-05-15 00:00:00  0.59601         0           
11      B  2023-05-16 12:00:00  0.59548         0           
12      B  2023-05-17 06:00:00  0.59444         0  Lower Low
13      B  2023-05-18 02:00:00  0.59527         1
```